# Java to C# - BigInt.modPow

Tags: java, c#, math, numeric

Okay so I'm trying to convert a method from Java to c#, however modPow in C# takes 3 arguments, where as in Java it only takes 2? How can I convert the following to C# -

```
BigInteger var6 = var5.modPow(var1, var2);
```

Tried the following but it returns exceptions -

```
BigInteger var6 = var5.ModPow(var1, var2);
```

stating - DivideByZero Exception, ArgumentOutOfRangeException..

which is obviously due to the fact there's only 2 arguments instead of 3, however I don't want to add a blank argument as it may cause the functionality to not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java the `modPow` method is exposed against an instance of `BigInteger` whereas in C# it is a [static method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) on the `BigInteger` class. See the docs for [ModPow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow?view=netframework-4.7.2). This means you need to do this:

```
BigInteger var6 = BigInteger.ModPow(var5, var1, var2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the "missing" argument. When you'd do `x.modPow(y, z)` in Java, do `ModPow(x, y, z)` in C#.